# How can I give normal user to access "log in as other user" privilege without giving them system admin rights?

Tags: grant-login-access, grant-login

I want to give user the right to "login as another user"

[image]

so that the user can view other user's perspective.

I cannot see any other way other than giving them system admin privilege, which is not recommended for obvious reasons.

I don't want to give him rights to create users or edit users data in anyway (he will get edit rights for the user he is logged in as, but that's neglectable)

Is there any other way out?

Answer (score 8):

You can add them to the group with such rights

http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=delegating_user_administration.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Can you elaborate how you see this working and what permissions you're talking about ? I didn't know this was possible.

Comment: You can make some users Delegated Administrators for a certain users in the Role Hierarchy subset. You can also restrict what profiles they can assign to the users for whom he is the Delegated Admin of. With this right, the Delegated Admin can login as those users in that particular hierarchy subset.

Comment: what if I don't want any admin rights? I don't want that user to have user creation/change profile etc...

Comment: @Saariko I think you've wasted 50 pts :/ This help link is pretty descriptive. To BE a delegated admin you need only "View Setup and Configuration". My users effectively use this during testing and they don't have any special powers, they can't even see Roles & Queues for example. And they certainly don't have "Manage Users".

Comment: I dissagree with the "wasted" comment. 1. We got another answer (increase the A:Q ratio) 2. Someone will get 50 points for their answer. 3. I almost doubled the views on this Q 4. I got a new badge ^^

Comment: @eyescream http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_delegate.htm&language=en_US - Can create users... - Can't have that

Comment: Hmm... add a val rule on User that checks `ISNEW() && $Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'`?

Answer (score 1):

You could create and use a permission set with "Modify All Data" turned on and then assign that permission set to the user.

Comment: Or use Delegated Administration with a permission set.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of straight away is.. create another user and give this user the access that is required (setting the right profile and roles etc).

So, the user has to switch between the existing and this new user access.

Comment: I don't have spare licenses. Also, I need the 'owner' to view the data that the users see.